# React : Visualize blob data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visualization

I have a .wav format audio byte array stored inside a blob. In ReactJS, do we have any libraries to visualize the data inside a blob?

Backend

```
Fs.readfile(audiofile, data);
```

UI

```
Const blob = new blob(new Uint8arr(response.arraybuffer);
Const url = URL.creatrObjectURL(blob);
```

Sample visual:
[image]

Comment: What does it mean "show the data inside a blob"?

Comment: Visualize the audio which was stored as blob.

Comment: Sorry, what does `Visualize`  mean? Do you want to play the file?

Comment: I'm able to play the file. I'm looking to show the file (like a wave or spike) as updated in the question.